# tinyMCE - disable source formatting - div inside span

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rte

I need to insert this code in the RTE:

```
<div class="1">1
    <span class="2">2
        <div class="3">3
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Once again, inside the code, not in visual style. But the output will always look like this:

```
<div class="1">1
    <span class="2">
        <span class="2">2
        </span>
    </span>
    <div class="3">3
    </div>
</div>
```

The structure is like this due to reasons related to responsive layout.

RTE config(part of it)

```
image_advtab: true,
image_dimensions: false,
cleanup_on_startup: false,
cleanup : false,
trim_span_elements: false,
verify_html: false,
keep_styles: false,
valid_children : "    +a[h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text|span|div|noscript], +span[a|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text|span|div|noscript], +div[a|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text|span|div|noscript]",
visualblocks_default_state: false,
forced_root_block: false,
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
remove_linebreaks: false,
apply_source_formatting : false,
```

I've tried to remove all auto formatting, and I've tried all kinds of RTE config,  but it's not working.

Comment: By "RTE", do you mean "Rich Text Editor" as in the tinyMCE textfield?

Comment: `div` elements are block level and should not be inside of inline `span` elements. "reasons related to responsive layout" is no excuse. There are no such reasons!

Comment: Yes, I refered to tinyMCE.

Comment: Yes, I refered to tinyMCE. It's a long way to explain the situation, but trust me, so it is and I have to deal with it. Those span are used by a compressed js I cannot deflate, so I cannot change span with div in html.

Comment: But if you could disable source formatting (as you write in the title), is it still important to insert the div's? I feel like this is two questions.

Comment: I'm gonna correct miself, let's say I want so stop all marckup and tag autoclosing. So le's presume I made a mistake and I've put a div inside a span. So what? It will be rendered corrct by all browsers. And I want to leave it this way.

Comment: In fact the question resummes to: can it be done in tinymce or not? Iwon't change the html template.

Comment: @StefanTenovici You have plugins that does the highlighting and auto closing. Remove those from the list of plugins and see what happens.

Comment: @ Nicolai: do you know witch one? Because I couldn't figure out